# how to upload single file with multiple form inputs using multer in express js?

Tags: node.js, database, express, file-upload, multer

I have different form inputs to upload in a single page on how to upload using multer?

```
 app.js :

    const multer = require('multer');

    const fileStroge = multer.diskStorage({

      destination: (req, file,cb)=>{

        cb(null, 'upload');

      },


      filename: (req, file, cb) =>{

        cb(null, file.originalname);
      }
    });

    const fileFilter = (req, file, cb)=>{

        if(file.mimetype == 'application/octet-stream'){
          cb(null,true);
        }else{
          cb(null,false);
        }
    };

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extented: true}));
app.use(multer({ storage: fileStroge, fileFilter: fileFilter}).single('filename'));
// app.use(multer({ storage: fileStroge, fileFilter: fileFilter}).single('filenameS'));
```

below is my js file

```
user.js:

exports.uploadedData = (req, res)=>{

  const file = req.file;
  // console.log(file);
  if( file == undefined){
    res.send("you can upload excel sheet only");
  }
 readXlsxFile(req.file.path).then((rows) =>{


    var database = mysql.createConnection(
      { host: 'localhost', user: 'root', password: 'ilensys@123', database: 'harness_db'}
    );
    var query = database.connect(function(err) {

      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Connected!");
      var sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO harnes_detials (id, item_des, harness_drw_pin, harness_type, harness_conn_type, mating_crimp, design_volt, connectors_mating_mfg, mating_connector_part_no, design_current, gauge, connector_type, connect_gender, no_pins, no_rows, connectors, manufacture, contact_rating, voltage_rating, maximum_temp, connector_orientation, d_connector_type, d_connector_gender, d_mating_connector_part_no, d_connector_mating, d_connectors_mating_mfg, d_no_pins, d_no_rows,d_connector, d_manufacture, d_contact_rating, d_voltage_rating, d_maximum_temp, d_connector_orientation, d_guage, d_mating_crimp, createdAt, updatedAt) VALUES ? ";
    var newSql = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'req.file.path' INTO TABLE harnes_detials";
    var values = rows.slice(1);   
      // console.log(values);

    database.query(sql, [values], function (err, result) {
        // console.log(result);
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }else{
          res.render("success");
          console.log( "row inserted: "+ result.affectedRows);
        }
      });

    });

});

};

exports.uploadedSourceData = (req, res)=>{

  const file = req.file;
  // console.log(file);
  if( file == undefined){
    res.send("you can upload excel sheet only");
  }
readXlsxFile(req.file.path).then((rows) =>{


    var database = mysql.createConnection(
      { host: 'localhost', user: 'root', password: 'ilensys@123', database: 'harness_db'}
    );
    var query = database.connect(function(err) {

      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Connected!");
      var sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO matingsources (id, mating_source_connectors,connector_type, source_connectors, gauge) VALUES ? ";
    var newSql = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'req.file.path' INTO TABLE matingsources";
    var values = rows.slice(1);   
      console.log(values);

    database.query(sql, [values], function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }else{
          res.render("success");
          console.log( "row inserted: "+ result.affectedRows);
        }
      });

    });

});

};
```

below is my ejs file with inputs :

```
  <form class="needs-validation" action="/uploadData" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
          <div class="custom-file mb-3">
            <input type="file" class="custom-select custom-file-input" id="filename" name="filename" required>
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
            <div class="valid-feedback">Looks Good!</div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">need to upload a file!</div>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-3 text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
            <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="javascript:history.back()" role="button">Cancel</a>
          </form>

  <form class="needs-validation" action="/uploadSourceData" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
            <div class="custom-file mb-3">
              <input type="file" class="custom-select custom-file-input" id="filenameS" name="filenameS" required>
              <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
              <div class="valid-feedback">Looks Good!</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">need to upload a file!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-3 text-center">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
              <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="javascript:history.back()" role="button">Cancel</a>
            </form>
```

its works fine with the first input upload option but with I upload from second input from other input its says :

```
multererror: unexpected field
```

but when I comment alternatively its works for both:

```
 app.use(multer({ storage: fileStroge, fileFilter: fileFilter}).single('filename'));
    // app.use(multer({ storage: fileStroge, fileFilter: fileFilter}).single('filenameS'));
```

but how to work with two different inputs uploads on the same page?? please help ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the name attribute of the second input element to:

```
<input type="file" class="custom-select custom-file-input" id="filenameS" name="filename" required>
```

so that both input's have the same name attribute and then just use the multer route with 'filename'